# Project with local copy of external module doesn't build

Tags: go, go-modules

I have project that uses an external library which has a bug in it. To fix the bug, what I tried to do was to clone the external library, place it in a sub-directory within the project, and fix it there. So if the external library is `example.com/example/example/`, I just put it a folder named `example` within my project, delete the `example.com/example/example/` dependency from `go.mod`, and replace all `example.com/example/example/` import statements with `myproject/example/`

The problem is that the project doesn't compile. Whenever `go build` is executed, it returns an error: `no matching versions for query "latest"`. The only way I found to get the project to build is to delete the `go.mod` file of the cloned external library, but that just doesn't seem right. So what's the right way to build such a project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The right way to do it is using the [replace directive](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules#when-should-i-use-the-replace-directive).

The idea is to replace the the module name of the imported dependency **from the top level `go.mod` file**, without changing the external dependency.

So all I had to do was to add `replace example.com/example/example => ./example` to to **top level** `go.mod`.